# Mutex and broadcast signal

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Hello I am writing a code using pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_broadcast(). The objective of my code is to trigger four threads at a time which should run in parallel.When I am passing signal to four threads using pthread_cond_broadcast all the four are getting triggered serially.The triggered time for the four threads are as given below.

```
                  HH : MM : SS : MS : uS
  Thread 1        12 : 59 : 05 : 27 : 407
  Thread 2        12 : 59 : 05 : 27 : 586
  Thread 3        12 : 59 : 05 : 27 : 879
  Thread 4        12 : 59 : 05 : 28 : 113
```

**From the observation we can see that triggered time of four threads are varying so can anyone tell me what is the reason for that?**

Comment: (a) probably because the processor cores on your machine, assuming there is more than one, are re-scheduled at slightly different times (b) pthread_cond_signal makes no guarantee that threads it signals will be scheduled immediately nor at the same time.

Comment: Also: depending on how you are reading the time in each thread, it may be prone to variability/inaccuracy (across different processor cores etc).